# Dynamically change point color in Three.js PointClouod

Tags: three.js, point-clouds

I'm trying to render a matrix of points in Three.js but I need to treat each particle in the cloud as an individual "pixel" for which I can change the color of each on the fly. I figured out how to basically render the point cloud, and can set the initial color, but cannot figure out how to change the color of each point once it's set.

I'm generating the point cloud like this:

```
function generateRegularPointcloud( color, width, length ) {

                var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
                var numPoints = width * length;

                var colors = [];

                var k = 0;

                for( var i = 0; i < width; i++ ) {

                    for( var j = 0; j < length; j++ ) {

                        var u = i / width;
                        var v = j / length;
                        var x = u - 0.5;
                        var y = 0;
                        var z = v - 0.5;
                        var v = new THREE.Vector3( x,y,z );

                        var intensity = ( y + 0.1 ) * 7;
                        colors[ 3 * k ] = color.r * intensity;
                        colors[ 3 * k + 1 ] = color.g * intensity;
                        colors[ 3 * k + 2 ] = color.b * intensity;

                        geometry.vertices.push( v );
                        colors[ k ] = ( color.clone().multiplyScalar( intensity ) );

                        k++;

                    }

                }

                geometry.colors = colors;
                geometry.computeBoundingBox();

                var material = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial( { size: pointSize, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );
                var pointcloud = new THREE.PointCloud( geometry, material );

                return pointcloud;

            }
```

My basic code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dg34sbsk/

Any idea how to change each point color separately and dynamically? (Data for the colors will be coming in from a web service).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can directly change its's value `pointclouds[0].geometry.colors=...` and after that `pointclouds[0].geometry.colorsNeedUpdate=true`.
To set each point's color just set the *colors*'s children's value like `pointclouds[0].geometry.colors[22]=new THREE.Color("rgb(255,0,0)");`.

see this:http://jsfiddle.net/aboutqx/dg34sbsk/2/ .click and you will see the color of one point changes.

Comment: Don't use `color = new THREE.Color()`. Use `color.set()`, instead.

Comment: Well,that will be better,for less instances.

Comment: @WestLangley Can i ask why? Why is it better to do color.set instead of THREE.Color?

Comment: It avoids unnecessarily instantiating a new object.

Comment: It seems like `colorsNeedUpdate` is not a thing any more.  I ended up needing to instantiate my PointsMaterial with `vertexColors: true`, and then set colors with `this.points.geometry.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );`